# Given a specific datetime and a number of minutes, how do i calculate the end datetime only in workhours, excluding multiple breaks and day rollover?

Tags: mysql

I've got a peculiar problem, in which i have the starting datetime and i need to calculate the 'final' datetime, based on a variable X.

Basically, i've got a first table, with a few columns, one of which is datetime.

In another table, i've got a few "time" columns, which contain:

```
start_of_day, end_of_day, break1_start, break1_end, break2_start, break2_end (4 breaks in total), minutes_per_call
```

I need to take the datetime in the first table, and only add the actual minutes inside the work time of the day.

To add another layer of complexity, i need to avoid sats and suns.

I've tried, most i've reached is to calculate the day rollover, but i cant figure out how to complete it

Any hints?

In here i saw multiple times referencing other tables to calculate dates and times, but i couldn't find an example that matches my case - i'm stumped at the moment

```
CREATE TABLE `turns` (
  `LINE_TYPE` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `DAY_BEGIN` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `DAY_END` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `BREAKTIME1_BEGIN` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `BREAKTIME1_END` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `BREAKTIME2_BEGIN` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `BREAKTIME2_END` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `BREAKTIME3_BEGIN` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `BREAKTIME3_END` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `MINUTES_TO_COMPLETION` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`LINE_TYPE`)
);


INSERT INTO `WORKDB`.`TURNS`
(`LINE_TYPE`,
`DAY_BEGIN`,
`DAY_END`,
`BREAKTIME1_BEGIN`,
`BREAKTIME1_END`,
`BREAKTIME2_BEGIN`,
`BREAKTIME2_END`,
`BREAKTIME3_BEGIN`,
`BREAKTIME3_END`,
`MINUTES_TO_COMPLETION`)
VALUES
('TLD','08:00:00', '17:00:00', '10:00:00', '10:15:00', '12:30:00', '13:30:00', '15:00:00', '15:30:00', '300');


CREATE TABLE `calculation` (
  `LINE_TYPE` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `CALLTIME` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`LINE_TYPE`)
);

INSERT INTO `WORKDB`.`calculation`
(`LINE_TYPE`,`CALLTIME`)
VALUES
('TLD','25/09/2020 14:58:00')
```

From these, i need to have a select that gets me a calculated 'expected end time', excluding the breaks.
In the example, we have a call for identifier TLD that starts at 14:58:00 - the minutes to completion are calculated by adding the completion time, in this case 300 minutes.

The timer needs to run only inside working hours (which means, inside the day (DAY_BEGIN and DAY_END) and outside the breaktimes.

This particular case, would be:

14:58:00 is 2h2m till 5, minus 30m break time (15:00 to 15:30) is 1h32m to closing time.
Timer starts again at 8 following morning, until 10 (first break time), we've reached 2h32m.
at 10:15 we start again, till second lunch time, 4h47m.
at 13:30 we start again, and reach the 300 minutes target after another 13 minutes.

So, this timer (unless i messed up my calculations) would run out at nextday of call, 26/09/2020 13:43.

This is the data i need, and i'm at a loss as to how to do those calcs in mysql.

Comment: Provide DDL for both tables, some example data as INSERT INTO, and desired output for this data.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for you comment! Added what was missing

Comment: *1h32m to closing time. Timer starts again at 8 following morning, until 10 (first break time), we've reached 2h32m* I'd say 3h32m

Comment: Look at *[the way to solution](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=593865bfc0e7a17e8607b9fca2e6f349)*. It is performed slow-slow solving, step-by-step, and must be seriously optimized. I see the ways to optimization (calculate cumulative sum immediately in recursive CTE), but have no time now.

Comment: You've broken my brain. This is going to take me some serious time to understand - and i'll put in the effort; some of those funcs i never saw. This is gold, an extremely big thank you. I tested it and it works as expected. From what i'm seeing about the CTE it seems it would be easier on it to just have the 'turns' table be a range of working times, rather than ranges of breaks. I'll look into that and eventually change it to the fastest - the turns table i can work with, the other one can't. Can't thank you enough about this!